# Отправка нескольких писем из одной активити

Tags: android, email

Мне нужно отправить несколько писем разным получателям, но при этом текст писем может различаться. При этом я хочу авторизовать пользователя и слать письма от его имени, через `Intent` и встроенный почтовый клиент. И есть ли какой-либо способ не вызывать intent-ом для каждого из этих писем новое окно почтового клиента, чтобы пользователь подтверждал отправку каждого письма, а сделать это одним нажатием кнопки?

Comment: Письма от имени пользователя отправлять нельзя, можно только открыть шаблон, что вы и делаете. 
Напрямую и несколько можно отправлять через SMTP, но нужно знать логин и пароль пользователя

Comment: Вы часто встречаете почтовые клиенты, которые умеют из одной активити отправлять много разных писем за раз?

Comment: @Miha_x64, нет :) Я не думаю, что это тривиальный вопрос) Но вдруг есть какой-нибудь воркэраунд, обходной путь для реализации этого?

Comment: Несколько интентов по очереди.

Comment: что значит текст писем может различаться?

Comment: нужно отправить несколько писем разным получателям, и текст писем для разных получателей может быть разным